# Перебрать многомерный массив с данными и вывести в строки

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив с произвольной глубиной.

```php
$test_110 = [
    'dim' => [
        'dim2' => [
            'dim3' 
        ],
        'dim4' => [
            'dim5'
        ]
    ],
    'dim6' => [
        'dim7'
    ]
];
```

Нужно пройтись по нему и на выходе было три строки:
// output: dim/dim2/dim3
// output: dim/dim4/dim5
// output: dim6/dim7
Пока что удалось сделать это подсчёт рекурсивно глубины масива:

```php
function array_depth($a, $b = 0)
{
    $d = 0;
    foreach ($a as $v)
    {
        if (is_array($v))
        {
            $c = array_depth($v, $b);
            $d = ($d > $c) ? $d : $c;
        }
    }
    return $d+1;
}
echo array_depth($test_110);// output: 3
```

Как быть дальше?

Comment: Вам там точно тернарные операторы нужны?

Comment: Передавайте параметром массив, в который будете складывать путь. При ракурс и и возврате делайте пуш и поп. Когда достигли конца выводите там, или что то еще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На скорую руку... Надеюсь разберетесь.

```php
<?php
$test_110 = [
    'dim' => [
        'dim2' => [
            'dim3' 
        ],
        'dim4' => [
            'dim5'
        ]
    ],
    'dim6' => [
        'dim7'
    ]
];

function recursive_walk( $parent_key, $arr ) {
    if (is_array( $arr ) && count( $arr ) > 0 ) {
        if ( mb_strpos($parent_key, "/") !== false ) { echo $parent_key; }
        //Первый раз передаем $test_110 - получаем его ключи `dim`, `dim6`
        $keys = array_keys( $arr );
        //Для каждого элемента массива $test_110 вызываем еще раз эту же функцию и передаем как входной параметр под-массивы
        //$test_110['dim'], $test_110['dim6']
        //На втором вызове функции на вход попадет под-массив $test_110['dim'], у него получим ключи `dim2`, `dim4` - вызовем эту же
        //функцию для $test_110['dim']['dim2'], $test_110['dim']['dim4']
        //И так далее вглубь пока хватит памяти и последний элемент не будет массивом

        if ( is_array( $keys ) && count( $keys ) > 1 ) { 
            foreach( $keys as $key ) {
                recursive_walk($parent_key."/".$key, $arr[$key] ); 
            }
        } else {
            //Попали на элемент который не является массивом - например `dim3`, `dim5`, `dim7`
            //Просто выводим его
            echo ( mb_strpos($parent_key, "/") === false ? $parent_key : "")."/".$arr[0]."\n";
        }

    }
}

$keys = array_keys( $test_110 );
foreach( $keys as $key ) {
    recursive_walk( $key, $test_110[$key] );
}
```